# How to make Nvidia Optimus GT540m work on ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, unknown-device

I've already tried to follow literally everything on ask ubuntu and similar websites but still I cannot manage my graphic card:

- If I look under system settings "Graphics", Ubuntu seems unable to recognize any kind of graphic device (not even intel) since it says: "Driver Unknown"
- Under the tab "proprietary drivers" of the software center it is listed only the Broadcom card, but not nvidia.
- Still, if I run

  ```
  lspci| grep VGA
  ```

  the system returns:

  ```
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated
  Graphics Controller (rev 02)
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M]
  (rev a1)
  ```

  so the system knows that the graphic cards are there.
- I've already tried (after the installation of the kernel source and headers using -$(uname -r) to avoid problems) to install the bumblebee repositories and then the nvidia drivers, but still if I run:

  ```
  optirun glxspheres
  ```

  the system returns:

  ```
  [ 3740.367448] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU
  driver
  [ 3740.367550] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
  ```

I'm frankly bewildered and frustrated: what can I do or check now?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: yes, that's the result:

    [  296.503050] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: 
    [XORG] (EE) Failed load module "nvidia" (module does not    
    exit, 0)

Comment: Ensure that you have the headers package installed, see http://askubuntu.com/a/36936/6969. If you have also installed drivers other than nvidia-current (e.g. nvidia-current-updates), you also need to edit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf to reflect those changes. If you do not know what you are doing, just uninstall all nvidia-experimental and nvidia-current-updates packages and still to nvidia-current from ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates as described in the link.

Comment: I installed headers using:

$(sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r))

how do I check if they're correctly installed?

I also tried, as @Lekensteyn suggested to uninstall all nvidia-experimental and nvidia-current-updates and then reinstall nvidia-current (but from Bumblebee since under ubuntu-x-swat/x-updatesd it didn't found any nvidia package) using

$(sudo apt-get install bumblebee nvidia-current)

The situation worsened: after reboot the desktop was not showing, compiz was not working and "Graphics" still told "Drivers: Unknown"

Comment: You need to install both the bumblebee/stable and ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates PPAs. Remember to reinstall bumblebee-nvidia after installing nvidia-current. Something like `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current nvidia-current-updates nvidia-experimental-* bumblebee-nvidia && sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia`

Comment: Ok! The system settings still says "Drivers Unknown", but running optirun glxspheres now starts the GeForce graphical interface! 
Is there a way to manage which program to "optirun" beside launching them via terminal using optirun?
Thanks everybody for your help!!!!